# Find the base system

Tags: number-theory

In an unknown base system two numbers are written as $402$ and $302$ in the base $9$ system the product of these two numbers is $75583$. Find the unknown base.

Comment: This should be anwsered without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$75583$ in base $9$ is $50052=2^2*3*43*97$ in base 10

The unknown base $b$ is at least $5$ since $402$ start with a $4$

If $b>10$, $402_b*302_2 \geq (11*11*4+2)*(11*11*3+2)=177390 > 50052$ so $b\leq 10$

$402_b =2 \mod(b)$ and $302_b=2 \mod(b)$ so $75583_9=50052_{10}=4\mod(b)$

$$50052=2\mod(5)$$
$$50052=0\mod(6)$$
$$50052=2\mod(7)$$
$$50052=4\mod(8)$$
$$50052=3\mod(9)$$
$$50052=2\mod(10)$$

So $b=8$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i just want to ask why is 402 to the base b equal to 2 mod b.

Comment: @Meadara because $402_b=4*b*b+0*b+2$

Comment: I see, even though it is not obvious at first sight (for me)

Answer (score 2):

HINT.

You must solve the equation $(4x^2+2)(3x^2+2)=50052$, where $50052=(75583)_9=2^2\cdot3\cdot43\cdot97$.

Comment: Great solution but it doesn't work if the second digit is not $0$ because you would get some $x^3$ and $x$

Comment: Thats a bit too straaight foward and this question was made to solve without a calculator.

Comment: @stity this works more generally and is very simple, since the equation must have an integer root.